# Will google consider a UK language site and a US language site as duplicate?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I googled around this for some time now and the answer is not completely clear for me. I found a similar question here [Is defining an hreflang sufficient to avoid duplicate content penalties between US and UK sites with nearly identical content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93640/is-defining-an-hreflang-sufficient-to-avoid-duplicate-content-penalties-between) but this was regarding a web-shop, which was exactly why it was easier to do.

The website I'm working on is not a web-shop. The us site will be on a subdomain: us.example.com

I wonder weather there is a way to make sure that google will not consider uk and us sites as duplicate? As the content on both sites will of course be quite similar. I do know about hreflang, but are there other things to be done to make it easier for google? Or do you have some good tips for this issue?

Comment: We should have the answer to this question on this site already.  It appears to be asked at [Multidomain site with duplicate content for different countries](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86246/multidomain-site-with-duplicate-content-for-different-countries) but that doesn't have an answer.

Comment: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site) contains the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [hreflang tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) it makes it clear they're US/UK mirrors.

Pair them up and copy them to each page. It will tell search engines that they ARE identical (or similar) content but to serve them to the appropriate geolocation.

It's also possible to manually set a geotarget for a (sub)domain using Search Console. Add the subdomain and go to the [interntational targeting panel.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en)